# How to edit this php snippet?

Tags: php, wordpress

iam just in hurry while making a wordpress site for a customer and iam just stuck on this little snippet because i got no PHP skills. Basic thing, its a template for a plugin that displays the title of a event.
problem is. it is acting as a link. And i just want to remove that. Still displaying the title, unclickable.

```
<h4 class="mec-event-title"><?php echo $this->display_link($event); ?><?php echo $soldout.$event_color; ?><?php echo $this->get_label_captions($event,'mec-fc-style'); ?></h4>
```

i tried to edit the $this->displaylink($event); section but it just all caused nonstop loading loop on page

THANK YOU for help <3

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Do you want this title clickable ? or its already clickable and you want to remove   ?

Comment: its already clickable and i want to remove it. Those variables are from Modern Event Calendar.